# WPF UI Threading

Tags: wpf, multithreading, mvvm, telerik, backgroundworker

I am trying to update chart and draw some scatter points there. For that I am using `BackgroundWorker` class. It does job. But I noticed as soon as I add color to my Point class and want display points of different colors it crashes. Why? any ideas?

```
    public class ChartData
    {
        private readonly Brush Red = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        private readonly Brush Orange = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
        private readonly Brush Green = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);

        public ChartData(double x, double y)
        {
            this.XValue = x;
            this.YValue = y;
        }

        public double XValue { get; set; }
        public double YValue { get; set; }

        public Brush Brush{ get; set;}
    }

    <telerik:ScatterPointSeries XValueBinding="XValue" 
                            YValueBinding="YValue" 
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" >
        <telerik:ScatterPointSeries.PointTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Ellipse Width="10"
             Height="10"
             Fill="{Binding DataItem.Brush}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </telerik:ScatterPointSeries.PointTemplate>
    </telerik:ScatterPointSeries>
```

Exception: `Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject.`

Comment: How does it crash? What happens? Does it throw an exception and if so, what?

Comment: Yes, it throw exception `Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject.`

Comment: hmmm, have you tried setting the point data's brush on the GUI thread using the dispatcher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the message itself, you can't modify `DependencySource`(add,create,delete) from antoher thread. You can modify it from same thread which is in your case is UI thread.

As a way out you can put the code of `modifying dependency source on UI thread dispatcher`

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate()
            {
                // Code here for updating Dependency Source.
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately same results or application just get freezed. Can it be an issue because of MVVM? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, my fault. Did it in proper way. Works well! Thanks!